# InvalidQueryParameterValue in Query Blob Contents using REST API

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to query Azure query blob content through REST API, following the documentation below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents

I made my blob contents public for testing and a GET request to blob URI is giving the content, but making a post request to mentioned URI

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=query
(replaced myaccount, mycontainer and myblob)

gibing me following error

````
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:1c52fc4f-801e-0061-63fc-f98163000000
Time:2021-02-03T07:15:32.9547540Z</Message>
    <QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
    <QueryParameterValue>query</QueryParameterValue>
    <Reason />
</Error>```

blob content is JSON and Blob is a Block Blob type
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might use the [SharedKey for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-authorization-header) when using [Query Blob Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents) rest api.

If it's the case, you'd better add the steps or code about how do you build the `Authorization header`. There might be a minor error there.

I give it a try by using `sas token` for authentication(you can refer to [this link](https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-sas-token/) for how to generate `sas token` via azure portal or code), and it can work well.

Here is my request url:

```
https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/a11/my11.csv?comp=query&my_sas_token
```

And in postman, the `request headers` are as below:

[image]

the `request body` is as below:

[image]

And as you can see the test results in the above screenshots, the status code is 200, and we can get the expected blob content.

Comment: After adding SAS Token I got this error solved, Thanks for your help. but now it is showing. A required feature for this operation is not enabled on the account, BlobQuery. I searched for an option like this in Azure and not able to find it. How to enable this feature in my account?

Comment: @ASHMILHUSSAINK, what's your azure storage? general purpose v2 or others? are you querying a .json/.csv file or other types of file?

Comment: @Ican Yang, 
Storage is StorageV2 (general purpose v2) I have tried with Both .json and .csv

Comment: @ASHMILHUSSAINK the file is `block blob type`?

Comment: Yes the file is Block blob

Comment: @ASHMILHUSSAINK, I didn't see there is something to turn it on or off in the storage account. Please provide more details like the storage account like location / standard or performance tier etc. and it's better show us your detailed request and the settings.